# How could i put two array of string in an arraylist with multiple object type in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Given a Java object that has certain fields defined such as a User class:

```
public class User {
public String Largetext;
public String Mediumtext;

public User(String Largetext, String Mediumtext) {
    this.Largetext = Largetext;
    this.Mediumtext = Mediumtext;
}
```

And ListView is:

```
String[] excercise1 = {"Wide-Grip Pull-Up", "Wide-Grip Pull-Down", "T-Bar Row", "Seated Cable Row", "Close Grip Row", "One Arm Dumble Row", "Dead Lift"};
    String[] Detail = {"3 Set of 8-12 rep","4 set of 12-15 rep","3 set of 12,10,8 rep","3 set of 10-12 rep","4 set of 10-15 rep","3 set of 10-12 rep","4 set of 10,8,8,6"};
    ArrayList<User> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    final int[] imgs1 = {R.drawable.pullup_la, R.drawable.pulldown_la, R.drawable.tbar_la, R.drawable.seated_la, R.drawable.bend_la, R.drawable.onearm_la, R.drawable.dead_la};
    ListAdapter saruadapter = new Backcoutomadapter(this, arraylist, imgs1);
    ListView sarulistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SarulistView);
    sarulistview.setAdapter(saruadapter);
```

Now how could i merge this two array of string excercise1 and Detail to this arraylist. So i could this arraylist in Backcoutomadapter like this:

```
public class Backcoutomadapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
private int[] imgs1;
private String[] detail;

public Backcoutomadapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> excercise1, int[] imgs) {
    super(context, backcustom_row, excercise1);
    this.imgs1 = imgs;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items of arrays exercise1 & Detail have one to one relationship, ie. item at position 0 of exercise1 is related to item at position 0 of Detail, right? So, you can just write a for loop till the length of the array, take the strings from the array, & insert into the array list:

```
for(int i=0;i<exercise1.length();i++){
    User user = new User(exercise1[i], Detail[i]);
    arraylist.add(user);
}
```

Then pass this arraylist to Backcoutomadapter:

```
ListAdapter saruadapter = new Backcoutomadapter(this, arraylist, imgs1);
```

Override & implement the getView method to use the strings in ListView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);
    ................
}
```